# StorageFile store = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"~\Assets\KuchBhi.pdf");

Tags: c#

Before trying to run the following code for a metro app
 StorageFile store = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"~\Assets\KuchBhi.pdf");
I anticipated that the compiler would throw an exception since there is no file named as KuchBhi.pdf in the assets folder, but that is not what happens, instead the machine just jams with a black screen and no further execution happens... 
Can anyone tell me what could be the problem and how to resolve it.
Thank You

Comment: The compiler can't know whether or not the computer you run the software on has an image at that path. Remember, the compiler produces a binary that isn't restricted to running on your computer. It might even run on a computer where someone has manually modified your application package to have that file.

Comment: Also, I don't think `~\path` is the proper format. Either `path` for a relative path or `\path` iirc. Also, you may want `TryGetItemAsync`.